# couchdb missing file

Tags: couchdb

```
curl localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:tyler
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

I am logged into futon as tyler, so i know that user exists.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What OS and CouchDB version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Was the problem and fix noteworthy enough to mention here for the benefit of the rest of the community? If so, a more detailed explanation of the problem and solution would be helpful.  If not, perhaps the question should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if you create a server admin via the local.ini configuration file. No _users document is created in that case, but you can still log in via futon.